# How create an anchor in yacc ocaml in an AST

Tags: ocaml, yacc

I'm writing a parser in OCaml. I already wrote the parser; now I'm trying to relate tokens to build an AST. Here's a sample from the parser:

PARSER:

```
expr: 
  | THE boiluser HAS l_ent {structural($2,$4)}
;
boiluser:
  | USER boiluser USER {}
;

l_ent: 
  boiluser {[$1]}
  | l_ent boiluser{ [$2::$1] }   ;
```

In the AST, I want to link `$2` and `$4`. I'm thinking of using hash tables, but I don't know how to do that. When I "call" `$1`, how do I know to link it with `$4`?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear: I have a hard time understanding the english, and an even harder time (once it is deciphered) understanding what you are asking.

The generic advice is not to do any analysis/processing at the parsing phase: just parse your input, and return an AST that faithfully represent it (modulo disambiguations and trivial concrete syntax details). You will be able to implement any further processing (such as building an association table between some identifiers and some data) as a function that runs over the returned AST. That is much cleaner and much easier to do.

I see that you are using the old program ocamlyacc. Did you know about [Menhir](http://cristal.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/), a parser generator that is easier to use and results in better grammar descriptions (for example with variable names instead of `$1 $2 $3`)? If you have the opportunity, you should consider switching -- and if you're a student, consider reporting it to your teacher, so he can improve life for everyone by using menhir in his courses.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean by "create an anchor" so I make a guess based on your code:

The *type* of a rule is the type of its *right hand side*, so in your case the type of *boiluser* is *unit* (same goes for its value):

```
boiluser:
  | USER boiluser USER {}
```

so when your use it in another rule:

```
expr: 
  | THE boiluser HAS l_ent {structural($2,$4)}
```

the value of *$2* is always *unit*! The type of the rule *expr* would be the type of the function *structural*, the value whatever *structural* will return for the concrete values of *$2* and *$4*.